# gitlab-ci with docker executor: maven cannot retrieve scmbranch, buildScmBranch: UNKNOWN

Tags: git, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I use Gitlab-ci with a docker as an executor to build my maven project.

I use buildnumber-maven-plugin v1.4 to retrieve git information like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<groupId>com.xxxxxx</groupId>
<artifactId>xxxxxx</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<!-- ********************************************************** -->
<!--            PROPERTIES                                      -->
<!-- ********************************************************** -->
<properties>
    <revision>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    <xxxxxx.boilerplate.version>0.5.2-SNAPSHOT</xxxxxxxx.boilerplate.version>
    <spring.framework.versoin>2.2.1.RELEASE</spring.framework.versoin>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<!-- ********************************************************** -->
<!--            MODULES                                         -->
<!-- ********************************************************** -->
<modules>
    <module>client-ui</module>
    <module>application</module>
    <module>domain</module>
    <module>infrastructure</module>
</modules>
<!-- ********************************************************** -->
<!--            REPOSITORIES                                    -->
<!-- ********************************************************** -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>java-boilerplate-maven-bucket-release</id>
        <name>xxxxxx Java BoilerPlate</name>
        <url>s3://xxxxxxxxxx/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>java-boilerplate-maven-bucket-snapshot</id>
        <name>xxxxxx Java BoilerPlate</name>
        <url>s3://xxxxxxxxxx/snapshot</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<!-- ********************************************************** -->
<!--            DEPENDENCIES MANAGEMENT                         -->
<!-- ********************************************************** -->
<dependencyManagement>
    <!-- xxxxxxx JAVA BOILERPLATE        -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxxx.boilerplate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxxxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxxx.boilerplate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>security</artifactId>
            <version>${xxxxxxx.boilerplate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SPRING BOOT WEB STARTER            -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.versoin}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.versoin}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SPRING BOOT TEST STARTER           -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.versoin}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<!-- ********************************************************** -->
<!--            DEPENDENCIES                                    -->
<!-- ********************************************************** -->
<dependencies>

</dependencies>
<!-- ********************************************************** -->
<!--            VERSIONING                                      -->
<!-- ********************************************************** -->
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@xxx.Xxxx.XXX.XXX:xxxx/xxxxxx.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
<!-- ********************************************************** -->
<!--            BUILD                                           -->
<!-- ********************************************************** -->
<build>
    <!--            FILE NAME                                   -->
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${buildNumber}</finalName>
    <!--            PLUGINS                                         -->
    <plugins>
        <!-- delete nodjs build folders on maven clean -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>node/**</include>
                            <include>client-ui/dist/**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!--    mojo buildnumer maven plugin                -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <shortRevisionLength>8</shortRevisionLength>
                <scmBranchPropertyName>true</scmBranchPropertyName>
                <scmBranchPropertyName>scmBranch</scmBranchPropertyName>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!--    maven jar plugin                -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                        <Build-Branch>${scmBranch}</Build-Branch>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- maven antrun plugin            -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>echo-properties</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <echo message="buildnumber-maven-plugin properties:"/>
                            <echo message="  $${scmBranch}:                  ${scmBranch}" />
                            <echo message="  $${buildNumber}:                ${buildNumber}" />
                            <echo message="  $${timestamp}:                  ${timestamp}" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <!--            EXTENSIONS                                      -->
    <extensions>
        <!-- Amazon aws repository s3 pulgin -->
        <extension>
            <groupId>com.allogy.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-s3-wagon</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>
```

The problem is when I build my project on local, maven get all git information as expected, but when the build is executed on gitlab, it cannot retrieve the scm branch name, an I get this warning:

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ securteck ---
[INFO] Deleting /builds/securteck/securteck (includes = [node/**, client-ui/dist/**], excludes = [])
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (default) @ securteck ---
[INFO] ShortRevision tag detected. The value is '8'.
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/builds/securteck/securteck' && 'git' 'rev-parse' '--verify' '--short=8' 'HEAD'
[INFO] Working directory: /builds/securteck/securteck
[INFO] Storing buildNumber: efd0a966 at timestamp: 1586711200134
[WARNING] Cannot get the branch information from the git repository: 
Detecting the current branch failed: fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref

[INFO] ShortRevision tag detected. The value is '8'.
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd '/builds/securteck/securteck' && 'git' 'rev-parse' '--verify' '--short=8' 'HEAD'
[INFO] Working directory: /builds/securteck/securteck
[INFO] Storing buildScmBranch: UNKNOWN
```

I use the same maven version on both local and gitlab runner.

There is my gitlab-ci.yml content:

```
image: maven:latest

# Services goes here
services:
  - docker:dind

# Cache goes here
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository
    - frontend-app/node_modules/

# ENV variables goes  here

# Before script goes here

# Stages definition goes here
stages:
  - build

# Build stage
build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - yum install -y git
    - git --version
    - mvn --version
  script:
    - echo "****** start scripts of build stage ******"
    - mvn clean install --settings .ci/settings.xml --no-transfer-progress
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please show your full pom file.

Comment: please include your `.gitlab-ci.yml`

Answer (score 1):

Gitlab runners checkout the repo in detached mode. I don't fully understand what that means but basically you can't query that same information that you can in your local environment.

So, having the same issue what I ended up using is some environment variables that provides the same information.

The downside now is that in your local you don't have that information available when you build. So I use both. And I know that my prod build will have the ones that comes from the CI and the other will be ignored.

- doesn't work: `${buildNumber}` and `${scmBranch}`
- use instead: `${env.CI_COMMIT_SHA}` and `${env.CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}`
- you can also use information not related to the repo like `${maven.build.timestamp}` and `${project.version}`

Comment: When you say you use both, how can you conditionally identify which variable will be used ?

Comment: `Git-Branch: UNKNOWN` will show when building in the CI. otherwise will have the correct branch.

Comment: @ChintanRadia you can use a profile that activates when running on GitLab vs when running somewhere else, that tells your archiver (maven-jar-plugin in the example) which variables use.